# Selecting based on an if

Tags: sql, if-statement, select

Helo,

i am attempting to make a select

1st column, currentStatus, has 2 variations: 'Paid', 'Unpaid'

2nd column, payment_id, only gets populated once a payment was done, but there are situations where it does not get a payment_id, those i would like to ignore from the select.

I am trying to select is all the rows that have status Paid and Unpaid, but only select Paid if it has a payment_id, while Unpaid does not have a payment_id to get selected.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
status
FROM table_name          
WHERE
IF(status IN ('Unpaid'),  '', paid_id <> '')
```

This does not return any of the Unpaid rows tho, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to select is all the rows that have status Paid and Unpaid, but only select Paid if it has a payment_id, while Unpaid does not have a payment_id to get selected.

The filtering logic you want:

```
where status = 'Unpaid' or
      (status = 'Paid' and paid_id is not null)
```

If `status` only takes on these two values, you can simplify this to:

```
where status = 'Unpaid' or paid_id is not null
```

Comment: Exactly that sir, no idea what i was thinking with the ifs, sorry my head is overheating today